# What does readonly mean or do?

Tags: bash, variable

What does readonly mean or do in this case? I have never seen or heard of it.

```
a="testString"; b=a; readonly b; b=25;
```

Also, would the final value of b at the end be 25?

Comment: run it and see it.it will help you for sure in the long way.

Answer (score 19):

It makes the variable read only. From `help readonly`:

```
readonly: readonly [-aAf] [name[=value] ...] or readonly -p
    Mark shell variables as unchangeable.

    Mark each NAME as read-only; the values of these NAMEs may not be
    changed by subsequent assignment.  If VALUE is supplied, assign VALUE
    before marking as read-only.

    Options:
      -a    refer to indexed array variables
      -A    refer to associative array variables
      -f    refer to shell functions
      -p    display a list of all readonly variables and functions

    An argument of `--' disables further option processing.

    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless an invalid option is given or NAME is invalid.
```

`$b` will always return "1" when creating b with readonly. As an example:

```
$ a=1
$ a=2
$ readonly b=1
$ b=2
bash: b: readonly variable
$ echo "$a"
2
$ echo "$b"
1
```